# How do I avoid problems when going from Wi-Fi to cell data connection (3G)?

Tags: wi-fi, data-connection

I have my phone (Droid X) connected to my home Wi-Fi network, but when I leave it can take applications (Google Maps, Rhapsody, etc) probably 10-15 minutes before they function normally without either doing nothing and/or giving data connection errors.

Something that may be telling (or meaningless) is that the little "3G" icon on the notification bar doesn't appear for a good long while.

Disabling the Wi-Fi on the phone after the fact doesn't seem to help, and the fastest method seems to be just power cycling the whole device.  Is there some better/cleaner/faster way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using [Quick Settings](http://www.appbrain.com/app/quick-settings/com.bwx.bequick) to toggle the 3G connection.  It has seperate toggle switches for 3G and Wifi but when wifi is on it automatically turns off 3G.  When I click the toggle to turn on 3G it automatically disables the wifi.

Answer (score 2):

Matt's answer is great, but you could also try:

1. Shut off WiFi
2. Turn on flight mode (`Settings -> Wireless and network`)
3. Turn off flight mode
4. Hopefully you should get a 3G connection within seconds

Here's another method (might be device-specific or 2.2+ only, not sure; it works on my Galaxy S):

1. Shut off WiFi
2. Hold your power button for a second to bring up the power/network menu
3. Click "Data network mode" to deactivate 3G
4. Click it again to reactivate 3G
5. Hopefully you should get a 3G connection within seconds